# Android View Displaying twice

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

This is what I mean by displaying twice.  Both of them are able to scroll depending on where you place your finger.

[image]

I have a basic adapter that doesn't do anything other than load the view (which has some placeholder data seen above).

Here is where the view is referenced in the adapter:

```
    @Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_item_forecast, parent, false);

    return view;
}
```

And the Adapter is call in a fragment here:

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

    mForecastAdapter = new ForecastAdapter(getActivity(), null, 0);


    ListView forecastListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView_forecast);
    forecastListView.setAdapter(mForecastAdapter);

    forecastListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
            // CursorAdapter returns a cursor at the correct position for getItem(), or null
            // if it cannot seek to that position.
            Cursor cursor = (Cursor) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);
            if (cursor != null) {
                String locationSetting = Utility.getPreferredLocation(getActivity());
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DetailActivity.class)
                        .setData(WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.buildWeatherLocationWithDate(
                                locationSetting, cursor.getLong(COL_WEATHER_DATE)
                        ));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}
```

I also have a cursor loader in that fragment that swaps the cursor onLoadFinished and onLoaderReset.

My layout.xml file, just in case it's relevant.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!-- Layout for weather forecast list item for future day (not today) -->
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/list_item_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_item_date_textview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Tomorrow"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_item_forecast_textview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Clear"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_item_high_textview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="81"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_item_low_textview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="68"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Asked for my MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String LOG_TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private final String FORECASTFRAGMENT_TAG = "FFTAG";
    String mLocation;


    private void showMap(Uri zipCode){
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setData(zipCode);

        if(intent.resolveActivity(this.getPackageManager()) != null){
            startActivity(intent);
        }else{
            View view = getCurrentFocus();
            Snackbar.make(view, "No Map application found", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).setAction("", null).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
//        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
//
//        mLocation = Utility.getPreferredLocation(this);
//
//        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "onCreate()");

        mLocation = Utility.getPreferredLocation(this);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.fragment, new ForecastFragment(), FORECASTFRAGMENT_TAG)
                    .commit();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "onDestroy()");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "onStart()");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if(mLocation != Utility.getPreferredLocation(this)){
            mLocation = Utility.getPreferredLocation(this);
            ForecastFragment ff  = (ForecastFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(FORECASTFRAGMENT_TAG);
            ff.onLocationChange();
        }
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "onResume()");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "onStop()");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "onPause()");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

        Context context = getApplicationContext();
//        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
//            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Settings Pressed", duration);
//            toast.show();

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, SettingsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

            return true;
        }else if(id == R.id.action_map_view){
            SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplication());
            String zipCode = preferences.getString(getString(
                    R.string.pref_location_key),
                    getString(R.string.pref_location_default));


            Uri geolocation = Uri.parse("geo:0,0?").buildUpon()
                    .appendQueryParameter("q", zipCode)
                    .build();

            showMap(geolocation);
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

This is the main_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.android.sunshine.app.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <!--<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton-->
        <!--android:id="@+id/fab"-->
        <!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
        <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
        <!--android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"-->
        <!--android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"-->
        <!--android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />-->

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And this is the content_main.xml that is referenced:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
    android:name="com.example.android.sunshine.app.ForecastFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main" />
```

Comment: why you do not use RecyclerView ?

Comment: Can you provide the code for your activity?  The problem is likely there

Comment: Just posted the activity @user3331142.

Comment: As for RecyclerView, I am following a tutorial and that is what they are using in this case @darushdary

Comment: Could you also display your main activity xml?

Comment: @user3331142 added the xml files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have seen this sort of behavior before with fragments.  It indicates that you have more than one fragment that has been attached to the activity.  Each with its own functioning listview.  I am unsure how this is happening as of yet in your code.

**EDIT**

Two fragments are being attached in the following places.

Once in your xml:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
    android:name="com.example.android.sunshine.app.ForecastFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main" />
```

And once in your Activity:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.fragment, new ForecastFragment(), FORECASTFRAGMENT_TAG)
                    .commit();
```

To fix this, remove

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.fragment, new ForecastFragment(), FORECASTFRAGMENT_TAG)
                    .commit();
```

in your `onCreate()` of your activity and you'll now have just one list displaying.

Comment: Did this answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to add the fragment in the `onCreate` since you have declared it in the xml:

Remove this from your `onCreate`:

```
  if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragment, new ForecastFragment(),FORECASTFRAGMENT_TAG)
                .commit();
    }
```

And make it this:

```
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    mLocation = Utility.getPreferredLocation(this);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}
```